# Hide navBar of a webview within a view swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I wanna hide a navbar that my webview has. The webview is within a view and it's inside a view controller.

The problem is that I don't want to show the navigation bar of the webview. I have to choices:

1) hide the navbar of the webview behind the navbar of the viewcontroller
2) Hide the navbar using javascript.

Any idea of how can I do that?

Comment: It's a hack, but if you have no control of the website, you can inject JavaScript into the web view once it's loaded using `evaluateJavaScript`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript

Comment: @paulvs Yes I know that it works but wanna find a better solution :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false // or true
```